# Adding new parameter to existing Rest service

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I have an existing Rest service in Java backend like such:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/service/{a}/{b}/{c}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Response service(@PathVariable Long a, @PathVariable String b, @PathVariable String c, @RequestBody List<String> d)
```

It is being called by JS in a GUI as such:

```
$http.post(
'/service/'
+ a + '/'
+ b + '/'
+ c,
d)
```

I simply need to add a new parameter "e", and have tried adding it as a new path variable:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/service/{a}/{b}/{c}/{e}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Response service(@PathVariable Long a, @PathVariable String b, @PathVariable String c, @PathVariable String e, @RequestBody List<String> d)
```

```
$http.post(
'/service/'
+ a + '/'
+ b + '/'
+ c + '/'
+ e,
d)
```

But JS fails to call the service now. From what I can tell this should work fine. Am I missing something?

Running code on Tomcat 8.5, accessing GUI through Google Chrome version 78.0.3904.87. Following errors appear in console:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at angular.min.js:6
    at r (angular.min.js:127)
    at n.$apply (angular.min.js:135)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:252)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at FiberInvenInfoController.fiberInfo.disconnectAllCircuits (FiberInvenInfoController.js:714)
    at n.$scope.ok (ModalServiceFiberInfo.js:428)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:212), <anonymous>:2:197)
    at f (angular.min.js:252)
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:108
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:80
$apply @ angular.min.js:135
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:252
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
FiberInvenInfoController.fiberInfo.disconnectAllCircuits @ FiberInvenInfoController.js:714
$scope.ok @ ModalServiceFiberInfo.js:428
fn @ VM866:2
f @ angular.min.js:252
$eval @ angular.min.js:134
$apply @ angular.min.js:135
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:252
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
angular.min.js:92

POST http://.../rest/fiber/disconnectCircuits/7977/11-04-2019/user/PD 404
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:92
n @ angular.min.js:88
f @ angular.min.js:86
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:120
$eval @ angular.min.js:134
$digest @ angular.min.js:132
$apply @ angular.min.js:135
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:252
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Comment: Did you remember to deploy the updated server code?

Comment: I published to local tomcat 8.5, ran in debug mode, and cleared cache in chrome browser. The updated code is visible in the debugger. I will have to check again for any errors; I am not very handy with front end code and debugging.

Comment: I was able to get some error information out of the log and will add it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably bug in Spring, look here:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6741
It is fixed in v4.1.

Comment: When I get a chance I’ll check the spring version and try calling a brand new rest service with the same parameters.

Comment: Calling a brand new service similarly gives a 404 error. It seems like spring is not refreshing my services.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot was not picking up the changes to new or existing Rest controllers. Removing default package from the project, and doing a Project Build before each Publish to Tomcat has solved the issue.